# Laravel : Anyone know how to foreach api from database?

Tags: laravel, database, laravel-8

im new to laravel

I Have this data on my database Tiktoks table :

| Id | Username |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Example |

And I have this on my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Tiktok;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $ttapi = new \Sovit\TikTok\Api(array());
        $username = Tiktok::select(['username'])
        ->get()
        ->toArray();

        $userinfo = $ttapi->getUser($username);

        return view('admin.dashboard.index', compact(['userinfo']));
    }
}
```

If you see in `$userinfo` i have `$ttapi->getUser`, how can I foreach everydata using 1 data from Tiktoks table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `->toArray()` from your code

Comment: Thanks for replying, but i got this error `foreach() argument must be of type array|object, bool given`